# How to use curl -XGET in python

Tags: python, curl, elasticsearch

I have a curl command which i want to use in python version 2.7.
curl -k -XGET '' -d ''
But I am not finding any appropriate function in [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library or [pycurl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl) library. I can only find simple curl get command alternates in it. But i need to post a JSON object which is a query to elasticsearch. Any help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for get request you can use library requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

```
import requests

response  = requests.get(url, data=your_data)
```

your_data is a dict of data in json format.

Comment: The important thing to realize, is that -XGET is just a simple GET. And since GET is the default for curl, you can actually omit it altogether for the curl request. -X in curl is followed by the http verb to use, so in the elastic search doc -XPUT is just a PUT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for posting json and getting the response back:

```
import json
import urllib2
data = json.dumps(['a', 'b', 'c'])
url = <define the url to be called>
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
resp = f.read()
f.close()
```